# 10 lines max with 14 characters in each line along with backspace in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I am trying to have a textview with 14 characters in each line and allowing user to enter 10 such lines. The 15th character is a new line character in every line. The problem arises when user tries to edit text in between the existing line text. Newly added text goes at the end of the entire text. It's because I am adding line break after 14th character when user starts typing due to which cursor goes at the end and text gets added there. I somehow managed to solve this by setting the cursor position but still when text goes to new line, characters are changing their positions. Backspace is also creating problem due to this. Will Appreciate any help !!!

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    return NO;
}

NSMutableString *fullstring = [[textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text] mutableCopy];

NSInteger intCharcount = fullstring.length - range.length + text.length;

const char * _char = [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");

if (isBackSpace == -8) {
}
else{

    textView.text = [textView.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

    for (i=0; i<intCharcount; i++) {

        if (i>0 && i%15 == 0) {
            NSMutableString *fullstring = [textView.text mutableCopy];
            [fullstring insertString:@"\n" atIndex:i-1];
            textView.text = fullstring;
        }
        else{
            textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(range.location, 0);
        }
    }

    if (intCharcount >= 151) {
        return NO;
    }
}

return YES;
```

}

Comment: share your code otherwise its impossible to assess whats going wrong.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. This is how my code looks.